# How to convert a string containing an embedded object to object type?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string formed by concatenating two separate strings (received in parts separately). The concatenated string is in actual an object. Now I need this concatenated result to be accessed as an object. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

My concatenated string is `"{\"access\":\"p2jlm3CJ\",\"refresh\":\"1//1LD77bbMqUc\"}"`

Desired object from this string is `{"access":"p2jlm3CJ","refresh":"1//1LD77bbMqUc"}`

Comment: unless I have missed something but a simple `JSON.parse` would convert your input string to your expected output

Comment: Just for completeness: `const parsedObject = JSON.parse(stringObject);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string is already an object converted into a string. You can just convert it back into an object:

```js
const input = "{\"access\":\"p2jlm3CJ\",\"refresh\":\"1//1LD77bbMqUc\"}";

const output = JSON.parse(input);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex to remove the \ from your string

```
var name="{\"access\":\"p2jlm3CJ\",\"refresh\":\"1//1LD77bbMqUc\"}"
var result = name.replace(/[\]/g);

console .log(result)
```

and then use the parse() method to convert the string to a JSON object.

```
const obj = JSON.parse(result);
console.log(obj)
```